# How should I write the units for MSE in its formula and in a plot axis?

Tags: mse, reporting, units, publication-bias

I am trying to write a paper for IEEE and would like to know if for MSE, which can have any units, it correct to write "MSE (error^2)" in its formula (i.e. MSE (error^2) = ) and in a plot axis. I am making price predictions and thus, for my context, MSE would have "US Dollars squared" as units. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: the rmse would be more intuitive

Comment: Yes that sounds great; as @seanv507 is intimating, many folks have trouble imagining squared dollars, so showing rMSE in dollars would be even better :)

Comment: Thanks @seanv507 and John Madden, but I'm using the MSE metric as it is the one that is most used in price prediction and that is how I have made my charts anyways. Therefore, should I write any units (Dollars squared or error squared) or leave it be. What have you both encountered in academic literature?

Comment: Regardless of what is in literature, which in my experience is often no units at all, for your context I would much prefer (USD squared) or (US dollar squared). Error squared is  pointless as MSE already conveys this.

Comment: That said, I support RMSE over MSE any day. Does no one study dimensional analysis any more?